# How do I calculate required Sample Size to get useful confidence interval length for Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: sample-size, population, confidence-interval

I am pulling meta data fields from a population of 100M documents. These meta fields include things like Author Name, Author Location, Keywords, etc. Some documents have all of these meta fields, some documents have a few of these fields, and some documents don't have any. We have no idea what the meta field coverage rates are for the population, but would like a best guess from a sample before we process the entire set ( eg. 45% of documents will include an Author Name ... 5% will include an Author Location ).

Basic sample size calculation suggest that I need to analyze 166 random documents to be 99% confident that my sample represents the population ( 99% Confidence Level ), while having a Confidence Interval of plus or minus 10% on the coverage rates we discover.

Intuitively, however, this does not seem like the correct method to me. If a meta field occurs very rarely in the full population, it seems like I'd have to adjust my population or change the Confidence Interval for that specific Meta Field.

How should I design this test to get valid coverage rates for meta fields representative of the complete population of documents?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as you notice, the length of a CI for the parameter of a Bernoulli random variable depends on the same variable. At 50% the CI is shorter, at the tails it is longer. So you cannot give a uniform error bound for all fields, unless in all fields the same proportion of entries is empty.

Comment: So say I only care about meta fields that occur in my sample population >25% of the time. How do I calculate the required sample size to reach a given Confidence Level and Interval at 25% occurrence? Would this represent "worst case" confidence for fields with higher occurrence percentages?

Comment: Yes, confidence intervals will only become shorter as $p$ increases towards 50%. By the way, (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51851/how-does-the-confidence-interval-for-the-parameter-p-of-a-bernoulli-trial-vary-w) covers your question entirely, with references.

Comment: Horst, do you have 'shorter' and 'longer' flipped around there? The variance $\pi(1-\pi)/n$ has a maximum at 0.5, which implies the standard error is largest when $\pi=0.5$, and so - at least for large $n$ - CIs should also be larger for  $\pi=0.5$ than for small $\pi$. It's possible I've misunderstood your point, but either way it would be good to make it clear.

Comment: Right, I confused something as I thought about it in Pearson-Clopper-bounds. So the worst case length can be found for $\pi = 0.5$.